# ¿Como puedo llegar a la solución si en el diccionario no puedo tener dos claves iguales?

Tags: python

Dada esta lista de diccionarios:

```py
boletas = [
{'fecha_compra' : '29-05-22',
'precio' : 12000,
'productos' : {'Chocolate': 1,
'Mantequilla': 1,
'Huevos': 12,
'Pan' : 1
    }
},
{'fecha_compra' : '31-05-22',
'precio' : 2400,
'productos' : {'Pan': 1, 'Leche' : 2}
},
{'fecha_compra' : '01-06-22',
'precio' : 3000,
'productos' : {'Mantequilla': 2, 'Azucar' : 1}
}
]
def precio_mes_boleta(boletas):
 mes_precio = []
    for i in boletas:
        mes_precio.append((i['fecha_compra'], i['precio'])) #agrega a la lista fecha y precio compra
    diccio = dict(mes_precio)   #crea un nuevo diccionario a partir de la lista
    nuevo_diccionario = {}  #creo un nuevo diccionario para cambiar las claves por          mm.aa
    for fecha, valor in diccio.items():
        mes_agno = fecha[3:]
        nuevo_diccionario[mes_agno] = valor
    return nuevo_diccionario        
print(precio_mes_boleta(boletas))
```

Mi problema es que el resultado esperado debe ser:
`{'05-22' : 14400, '06-22' : 3000, }`
y el resultado que obtengo es:
`{'05-22': 2400, '06-22': 3000}`, dado que debo sumar los totales de cada mes y en el diccionario no puedo tener dos claves iguales como se podria resolver?

Comment: Pon un título _descriptivo_ a tu pregunta, así lograrás atraer más atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tenes es que estas usando un arrelgo (e.g.: `mes_precio = []`) en lugar de un diccionario (e.g.: `mes_precio = {}`)

Si definimos `mes_precio` como un diccionario, necesitamos saber si la fecha ya existe para incremetar el valor almacenado o inicializarla. Esto lo podemos hacer así:

```
mes_precio = {}
fecha = '05-22'
if fecha in mes_precio:
    # fecha SI existe en mes_precio
else:
    # fecha NO existe en mes_precio
```

#### Solución:

Aplicando dicho cambio, tu código podrías ser el siguiente:

```py
boletas = [
    {
        "fecha_compra": "29-05-22",
        "precio": 12000,
        "productos": {"Chocolate": 1, "Mantequilla": 1, "Huevos": 12, "Pan": 1},
    },
    {
        "fecha_compra": "31-05-22",
        "precio": 2400,
        "productos": {"Pan": 1, "Leche": 2}
    },
    {
        "fecha_compra": "01-06-22",
        "precio": 3000,
        "productos": {"Mantequilla": 2, "Azucar": 1},
    },
]


def precio_mes_boleta(boletas):
    mes_precio = {}
    for i in boletas:
        
        fecha = i["fecha_compra"][3:]
        if fecha in mes_precio:
            mes_precio[fecha] += i["precio"]
        else:
            mes_precio[fecha] = i["precio"]

    return mes_precio

print(precio_mes_boleta(boletas))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://pythonsandbox.com/code/pythonsandbox_u70574_vuzqAv80bGVEKQMrqW6thtqI_v0.py)</kbd>